# Change login info in Screen Sharing recents list

Tags: big-sur, login, screen-sharing

Running Big Sur 11.2.1 on my laptop, I have a Mac Mini I connect to via Screen Sharing -- it is in the Recents list.  However, the Mini's login changed, and I can't update it:

- Changing it when logging in doesn't do it (it works for that login, but next time it reverts to the old values).
- I've looked at the .vncloc file in **~/Library/Containers/com.apple.ScreenSharing/Data/Library/Application Support/Screen Sharing** but there's nothing in there about login info.
- I've deleted the .vncloc file, but when I enter the address of the mini (it's at a fixed IP), it presents me with the old credentials again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credentials are stored in your keychain, which you can browse using Keychain Access.app in the Utilities folder of Applications.

Search for items named the hostname (or IP) of the device and delete the relevant password item.

Comment: Thanks grg.  I happened to find a post with that in it, and tried it -- but the old info persisted in Screen Sharing.  However, it didn't come back in my keychain!  Going to update to the latest Big Sur version tonight, maybe that will shake it out.

Comment: UPDATE:  Looked at my keychain again, and now there's an entry for that Mini, with the right credentials...but when I use Screen Sharing, it *still* shows the old login/pwd.  Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: UPDATE 2:  Fixed.  This Mini actually replaced another Mini in that subnet, and took over its fixed IP address.  I looked thru all the Minis in my keychain, and there was the old one with the old credentials.  Deleted it, and that fixed it.

Thanks again, @grg, I wouldn't have dug in further on that path without your suggesting it.

(Someone make that the accepted answer; not enough points here for my vote to count)

Comment: @Lonnie Good to hear you’ve sorted it out! You (and only you) can accept the answer using the check mark on the left under the voting buttons regardless of reputation. Thanks